# get the result from array of discrete forurier transform

Tags: c#, dft

I just wrote the implementation of dft. Here is my code:

```
        int T = 2205;

        float[] sign = new float[T]; 
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < T; i++, j++)
            sign[i] = (float)Math.Sin(2.0f * Math.PI * 120.0f * i/ 44100.0f);

        float[] re = new float[T];
        float[] im = new float[T];
        float[] dft = new float[T];

        for (int k = 0; k < T; k++)
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < T; n++)
            {
                re[k] += sign[n] * (float)Math.Cos(2.0f* Math.PI * k * n / T);
                im[k] += sign[n] * (float)Math.Sin(2.0f* Math.PI * k * n / T);;
            }
            dft[k] = (float)Math.Sqrt(re[k] * re[k] + im[k] * im[k]);
        }
```

So the sampling freguency is 44100 Hz and I have a 50ms segment of a 120Hz sinus wave. According to the result I have a peak of the dft function at pont 7 and 2200. Did I do something wrong and if not, how should I interpret the results?

---

I tried the FFT method of AFORGE. Heres is my code.

```
      int T = 2048;

        float[] sign = new float[T];
        AForge.Math.Complex[] input = new AForge.Math.Complex[T];
        for (int i = 0; i < T; i++)
        {
            sign[i] = (float)Math.Sin(2.0f * Math.PI * 125.0f * i / 44100.0f);
            input[i].Re = sign[i];
            input[i].Im = 0.0;
        }

        AForge.Math.FourierTransform.FFT(input, AForge.Math.FourierTransform.Direction.Forward);
        AForge.Math.FourierTransform.FFT(input, AForge.Math.FourierTransform.Direction.Backward);
```

I had expected to get the original sign but I got something different (a function with only positive values). Is that normal?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code look correct, but it could be more efficient, DFT is often solved by FFT algorithm (fast-fourier transform, it's not a new transform, it's just an algorithm to solve DFT in more efficient way).

Even if you do not want to implement FFT (which is a bit harder to understand and it's harder to make it work on data which is not in form of `2^n`) or use some open source code, you can make your implementation a bit fast, for example by seeing that `2.0f * Math.PI * K / T` is a constant outside of inner loop, so you can compute it once for each k (move it outside inner loop) and then just multiply it by `n` in your `cos/sin` functions.

As for position and interpretation, you have changed your domain, now your X-axis, which is the index of data in table corresponds not to time but frequency. You have sampling of `44100Hz` and you have captures `2205` samples, that means that every 1 sample represents a magnitude of your input signal at frequency equal to `44100Hz / 2205 = 20Hz`. You have your magnitude peak at 7th point (index 6) because your signal is 120Hz, so `6 * 20Hz = 120Hz` which is what you could expect.

Seconds peak might seem to represent some high frequency, but it's just a spurious signal, because your sampling rate is `44100Hz` you can not measure frequencies higher than `44100Hz / 2` (Nyquist's law) which if you cut-off point, after that frequency DFT data is not valid. That's why, second half of your table is invalid and it's basically your first half but mirrored and you can ignore it.

**Edit**//
From your questions I can see that you are interested in audio processing, you might want to google NForge.Net library, which is a great opensource library for audio and visual processing and its author have many good articles on [codeproject.com](http://codeproject.com) regarding many of it's features.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Yes, I need to make an application which is able to compute the fundamental frequency of voice in real time. I just tried the DFT first, but after I need to implement the FFT. Could you give me some good source how to understand/implement it? The other thing if one unit is 20Hz then I can get frequencies only that can be divided by 20? Just beacuse if I set the frequency for example 127Hz the result is the same when it is 120Hz.

Comment: @user1707045 It's probably not the same, look closer, or at least it shouldn't, I've played with your code a bit and if you will fe. set frequency to 130Hz you should get 2 magnitue spikes at 120Hz and 140Hz corresponding indexes, but both will have lower magnitude, so you have 2 spikes telling you "you've got a sinusoid somewhere between 120 and 140Hz. Which means that you can "catch" all frequencies, but the more samples you have the more accurate the result will be.
Check my edit and links, if you google "aforge fft" you can find a lot of useful materials and that's just the beggining!